# Getting error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'Complex') despite overloading the << operator

Tags: c++, stream, overloading, operator-keyword

I am a newbie programmer and I am writing a simple program that adds two complex numbers. I have overloaded `<<` in the following way:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Complex &complex_num){

        output << complex_num.realPart << " + " << "(" << complex_num.imaginaryPart << ")i" <<endl;
        return output;

    }
```

My addition function is as follows:

```
Complex operator +(Complex &c2){
        Complex temp;
        temp.realPart=realPart+c2.realPart;
        temp.imaginaryPart=imaginaryPart + c2.imaginaryPart;
        return temp;
    }
```

In my main function, when I try to print out the result by typing in :

```
cout << "ADDITION OF THE TWO COMPLEX NUMBERS: "<<num1 + num2<< endl;
```

I get an error saying no match for operator `<<`. However, when I assign another object `num3 = num1 + num2` and then write the following code, the program runs fine.

```
cout << "ADDITION OF THE TWO COMPLEX NUMBERS: "<<num3<< endl;
```

What is happening here? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Also if you are looking for complex numbers in c++, check out [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)

Answer (score 8):

Your `operator+` returns a `Complex`, which is a temporary object. It doesn't work when used with the `operator<<`, because you are trying to bind it to a non-const reference argument.

A variable can be bound to a non-const reference, so that works.

The fix would be to take the argument to `operator<<` by const reference:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Complex const &complex_num);
```

so it now works for temporaries as well. Even better, it works for const arguments too.